# What does the "*A" and "*U" means in the "sctp assocs" display?

Tags: sctp

cat /proc/net/sctp/assocs

```
ASSOC-ID ASSOC     SOCK   STY SST ST HBKT TX_QUEUE RX_QUEUE UID INODE LPORT RPORT LADDRS <-> RADDRS HBINT INS OUTS MAXRT T1X T2X RTXC wmema wmemq sndbuf rcvbuf

13 ffff8800b93a9000 ffff8800ac752300 2   1   3  9176        0        0       0 20735 3905  48538  *192.168.44.228 <-> *A172.16.236.92             7500    10    10    2    0    0       23        1        0  2000000  2000000

0     ffff88042aea3000 ffff880422e88000 0   10  1  40840        0        0       0     9542    3868   3868  *10.127.58.66 <-> *U10.127.115.194      7500    17    17   10    0    0         0        1        0  8388608  8388608
```

Comment: Which kernel version do you use and on which distro?

Comment: >>lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

kernel version:
Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04

Comment: "4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04" - This looks to be the gcc version while I'm asking for the linux kernel version. Give me the output of `uname -a` and `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`